# first-child issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

:)

Why does my first paragraph not have a red background?

**HTML:**

```html
    <div class="item">
        <h1><a href="http://localhost/test">Test</a></h1>
            <p>This is a new entry </p>
            <p>This is a new entry</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

`.item p:first-child {background:red}`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tv90yrbz/

Many thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Because the `<p>` is not the first child :)

Comment: instead of using first-chid use .item p:nth-child(2) {background:red}

Comment: @siva: Though it might work for the exact sample code provided in question, it won't always work because there could be cases where the `p` is not the 2nd child also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's not the first child, the `h1` is.

You can use `first-of-type`:

```
.item p:first-of-type {background:red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tv90yrbz/2/

---

Older browsers aren't supported though:

http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type

Comment: Many thanks. Quick follow-up, how do I get it to just affect the first paragraph and not all the others on the page? demo> http://jsfiddle.net/tv90yrbz/3/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: You would probably have to use some extra class on the parent container. Or, if the container is the first `div` in the page then you could do `div:first-of-type p:first-of-type`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, Harry - thanks so much to you & Curt :-D